# Finding a recurrent relation or formula

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, combinations, sequence-of-function

The formulation of the original problem: "How many words can be made up of N sticks, if two sticks can make the letter i, and three sticks can make j?"

*Final task: create a formula (or recurrent ratio) that finds the value of the number of words for a given number of sticks.*

There may be some way to use combinatorics here.
The ratio of the number of sticks to the number of words:

1 stick — 0 words

2 sticks — 1 word

3 sticks — 1 word

4 sticks — 1 word

5 sticks — 2 words

6 sticks — 2 words

7 sticks — 3 words

8 sticks — 4 words

9 sticks — 5 words

10 sticks — 6 words

Comment: Hint: This sequence satisfies the recurrence$$a_n=a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$$with initial terms $a_1=0$, $a_2=1$, $a_3=1$. I believe you should have $7$ words for $10$ sticks but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the right sequence. I will continue with the example:

11 sticks — 9 words;
12 — 9;
13 — 13;
14 — 15;
15 — 18;
16 — 21;
17 — 27;
18 — 28;
19 — 36;
20 — 40;
...

Comment: Please list the cases for $10$ sticks. I have$$\{IIIII, IJJI,IJIJ,IIJJ,JJII,JIJI,JIIJ\}$$

Comment: Yes, you're right, thank you

Comment: Only I wanted to get formulas for the nth term as an expression, not a recurrent relation

Comment: Although possible to write a formula for the $n$th term it will not be particularly useful as it contains powers of the roots of the equation $x^3-x-1=0$ of which two are complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A valid word of length $n$ contains $i$ times $I$ and $j$ times $J$ such that $2i+3j=n$. We denote with 
\begin{align*}
S_n=\{(i,j)|2i+3j=n,\quad i,j\geq 0\}\qquad\qquad  n\geq 0
\end{align*}
the set of pairs $(i,j)$ from which valid words are built. The number of valid words $A(n)$ which can be built from $i$ times $I$ and $j$ times $J$ is
\begin{align*}
\binom{i+j}{i}
\end{align*}
since out of $i+j$ positions in a word of length $2i+3j=n$ we can select $i$ positions for $I$.

> We conclude a formula providing the number $A(n)$ of valid words of length $n$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{A(n)=\sum_{(i,j)\in S_n}\binom{i+j}{i}}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

Based upon (1) we derive another representation. In oder to so, we consider cases $n=6m+q$, with $0\leq q\leq 5$. We show exemplarily the derivation for $n=6m+2$.

**Case $n=6m+2$:**

We have 
\begin{align*}
n&\in\{2,8,14,20,\ldots\}\\
m&\in\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}\\
\end{align*}
and get
\begin{align*}
S_2&=\{(1,0)\}\\
S_8&=\{(1,2),(4,0)\}\\
S_{14}&=\{(1,4),(4,2),(7,0)\}\\
S_{20}&=\{(1,6),(4,4),(7,2),(10,0)\}\\
&\cdots
\end{align*}
It follows by inspection
\begin{align*}
A(n)=\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{(3j+1)+(2m-2j)}{3j+1}=\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{2m+j+1}{3j+1}
\end{align*}
the other cases can be solved similarly.

> We obtain this way
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{A(n)}&\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{2m+j+p}{3j+q}}\tag{2}\\
> \\
> \color{blue}{(p,q)}&\color{blue}{=
> \begin{cases}
> (0,0)\qquad n=6m\\
> (1,2)\qquad n=6m+1\\
> (1,1)\qquad n=6m+2\\
> (1,0)\qquad n=6m+3\\
> (2,2)\qquad n=6m+4\\
> (2,1)\qquad n=6m+5\\
> \end{cases}}
> \end{align*}

**Note:** A closed formula from (2) is not within reach. This is a consequence of Theorem 2.2.2 in *[Integral Representation and the Computation of Combinatorial Sums](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821845128)* by G. P. Egorychev which provides information about closed form computations of expressions of the form
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{a_1n+a_2j+a_3}{a_4n+a_5j+a_6}x^j
\end{align*}